# I can't get Compile to work

Tags: equation-solving, compile

I've got some problems with my code, and I try to make it faster. Some of you suggested me to split my problem, and I'm here...

I post the same function with and without Compile.

This is a support function and does not involve my question

```
r=8.314472
fug1 = Compile[{v, p, t, a, b},
Module[{y, z, vbv, vb, f1, f2, f3, f4, f},
y = b/(4 v);
z = (p v)/(r t);
vbv = Log[(v + b)/v];
vb = v + b;
f1 = (4.*y - 3.*y^2.)/(1 - y)^2.;
f2 = (4.*y - 2.*y^2.)/(1 - y)^3.;
f3 = (2.*vbv)/(r t*b)*a;
f4 = (vbv/b - 1./vb)/(r t)*a;
f = f1 + f2 - f3 + f4 - Log[z];
Exp[f]]]
```

g2 doesen't work and I don't know why

```
g2 = Compile[{p, t, a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2},
Module[{a, b, csd, vol, sol, vliquid, vvapor, fl, fv},
a = a0*Exp[a1*t + a2*t^2];
b = b0 + b1*t + b2*t^2;
csd = a/(r*t*(b + v)) - (-(b^3/(64.*v^3)) + b^2/(16.*v^2.0) + 
    b/(4.*v) + 1.)/(1 - b/(4*v))^3 + (p*v)/(r*t);
vol = NSolve[csd == 0. && v > 0., v, Reals] // Quiet;
sol = v /. vol;
vliquid = Min[sol];
vvapor = Max[sol];
fl = fug1[vliquid, p, t, a, b];
fv = fug1[vvapor, p, t, a, b];
Print[{t, p, vol, Abs[fl - fv]}];
Abs[fl - fv]],
RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
```

This works without Compile!

```
g[p_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, a0_?NumericQ, a1_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ, 
  b0_?NumericQ, b1_?NumericQ, b2_?NumericQ] := 
Module[{a, b, csd, vol, sol, vliquid, vvapor, fl, fv},
a = a0*Exp[a1*t + a2*t^2];
b = b0 + b1*t + b2*t^2;
csd = a/(r*t*(b + v)) - (-(b^3/(64.*v^3)) + b^2/(16.*v^2.0) + 
    b/(4.*v) + 1.)/(1 - b/(4*v))^3 + (p*v)/(r*t);
vol = NSolve[csd == 0. && v > 0., v, Reals];
sol = v /. vol;
vliquid = Min[sol];
vvapor = Max[sol];
fl = fug1[vliquid, p, t, a, b];
fv = fug1[vvapor, p, t, a, b];
Print[{t, p, vol, Abs[fl - fv]}];
Abs[fl - fv]];
```

g works very well and is the same of g2!

```
FindRoot[g[p, 100, 500., -4.4627562855*10^-3, -2.7625748*10^-6, 
7.30402014*10^-2, -2.2222592*10^-4, 9.42486*10^-8], {p, 
34.376}] // Timing
```

g2 doesen't work

```
FindRoot[g2[p, 100, 500., -4.4627562855*10^-3, -2.7625748*10^-6, 
7.30402014*10^-2, -2.2222592*10^-4, 9.42486*10^-8], {p, 
34.376}] // Timing
```

Comment: There are many issues with with your functions. Variables are not localized, r is not defined in fug1, NSolve is not compilable and you probably mean to use g2 but are using function g1 in the FindRoot.

Comment: You're right. I've corrected it, I've localized my variables and I've inserted all your corrections, but it doesn't work again

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with solving your equation with Solve:

```
rv = r -> 8.314472;
csd = a/(r*t*(b + v)) - (-(b^3/(64*v^3)) + b^2/(16*v^2) + b/(4*v) + 
     1)/(1 - b/(4*v))^3 + (p*v)/(r*t);
rootsols = Solve[csd == 0, v] /. rv;
v /. Last[rootsols]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I change fug1 slightly:

```
fug1 = Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}, p, t, a, b}, 
   Module[{y, z, vbv, vb, f1, f2, f3, f4, f, r},
    r = 8.314472;
    y = b/(4 v);
    z = (p v)/(r t);
    vbv = Log[(v + b)/v];
    vb = v + b;
    f1 = (4.*y - 3.*y^2.)/(1 - y)^2.;
    f2 = (4.*y - 2.*y^2.)/(1 - y)^3.;
    f3 = (2.*vbv)/(r t*b)*a;
    f4 = (vbv/b - 1./vb)/(r t)*a;
    f = f1 + f2 - f3 + f4 - Log[z];
    Exp[f]]];
```

Now, g2, using Root instead of NSolve:

```
    g2 = With[{fug1 = fug1}, 
   Compile[{p, t, a0, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2}, 
    Module[{a, b, csd, vol, vliquid, vvapor, fl, fv}, 
     a = a0*Exp[a1*t + a2*t^2];
     b = b0 + b1*t + b2*t^2;
     sol = {};
     i = 0;
     While[i < 5, i++;
      soli =
       Root[-a b^3 + 
          8.314472` b^4 t + (12 a b^2 - b^4 p - 
             24.943416` b^3 t) #1 + (-48 a b + 11 b^3 p - 
             166.28944` b^2 t) #1^2 + (64 a - 36 b^2 p - 
             665.15776` b t) #1^3 + (16 b p - 532.126208` t) #1^4 + 
          64 p #1^5 &, i];
      If[Im[soli] == 0, sol = Append[sol, soli]]
      ];

     vliquid = Min[sol];
     vvapor = Max[sol];
     {fl, fv} = fug1[{vliquid, vvapor}, p, t, a, b];

     Abs[fl - fv]], {{soli, _Complex}, {sol, _Real, 1}}, 
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True},
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
    ]];
```

Testing with g:

```
g[p_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ, a0_?NumericQ, a1_?NumericQ, a2_?NumericQ, 
   b0_?NumericQ, b1_?NumericQ, b2_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{a, b, csd, vol, sol, vliquid, vvapor, fl, fv}, 
   a = a0*Exp[a1*t + a2*t^2];
   b = b0 + b1*t + b2*t^2;
   csd = a/(r*t*(b + v)) - (-(b^3/(64.*v^3)) + b^2/(16.*v^2.0) + 
        b/(4.*v) + 1.)/(1 - b/(4*v))^3 + (p*v)/(r*t);
   vol = NSolve[csd == 0. && v > 0., v, Reals];
   sol = v /. vol;
   vliquid = Min[sol];
   vvapor = Max[sol];
   {fl, fv} = fug1[{vliquid, vvapor}, p, t, a, b];
   (*Print[{t,p,vol,Abs[fl-fv]}];*)
   Abs[fl - fv]];
r = 8.314472; 
FindRoot[g[p, 100, 500., -4.4627562855*10^-3, -2.7625748*10^-6, 
    7.30402014*10^-2, -2.2222592*10^-4, 9.42486*10^-8], {p, 34.376}] //
   Quiet // Timing
```

gives

```
(* 
       {0.218401, {p -> 170.441}}
*)
```

and with the compile function (need a simple extra function g3 here):

```
g3[args__?NumberQ] := g2[args];
FindRoot[g3[p, 100, 500., -4.4627562855*10^-3, -2.7625748*10^-6, 
    7.30402014*10^-2, -2.2222592*10^-4, 9.42486*10^-8], {p, 34.376}] //
   Quiet // Timing
```

gives

```
(*
    {0.093601, {p -> 170.441}}
*)
```

So a speed-up of a factor of 2. Why not more? Because even though g2 compiles there is still a MainEvaluate (call-back to main Mathematica) to evaluate the Root object.
Maybe things will get even faster if you use a C-compiler.

Comment: I think the performance improvement here is due to your choice to express the problem slightly differently rather than because of `Compile`. Calls out of the VM are *very* expensive and there are just too many of them here to make compilation of `g2` worthwhile. (Although you forgot to localize `i`, it doesn't seem to make much difference overall.) Replacing `Compile` with `Function` actually improves the timings for me.

Comment: Thank's Oleksandr. Basically I just wanted to show how to get Compile to work at all. Did you test CompilationTarget -> "C" ? I have no time to investigate this further. Feel free to edit and extend my answer.